# NestJS: How can I inject the provider CACHE_MANAGER from CacheModule in a Dynamic Module without making the CacheModule global?

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs

If I make the CacheModule module global, the CACHE_MANAGER injection is available in my dynamic module, otherwise not.

The case:
The App Module (root module) has CacheModule imported.
And the same App Module imports a dynamic module, which internally uses the CACHE_MANAGER provider from CacheModule.

How can I inject the CACHE_MANAGER provider in my dynamic module?
Probably, I need to inject the CACHE_MANAGER provider somehow.